# DBI->Connect not working with mysql driver

Tags: perl

I have the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use  DBI;
use strict;
my $user = "test3";
my $password = "test3";
my $dsn = "dbi:mysql:hospital;localhost;3306";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password);
```

I am getting the error

```
Can't locate object method "driver" via package "DBD::mysql" at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBI.pm line 821.

Perhaps the capitalisation of DBD 'mysql' isn't right. at /Users/hrai36/Documents/test2.pl line 9.
```

I am very new to perl. I installed DBD::mysql using cpan. I don't know what Im doing wrong.

Comment: does a script that just does `use DBD::mysql;` work?

Comment: Change your DSN to `"DBI:mysql:database=hospital;host=localhost;port=3306"` and see if that works.